# Enabling logging for OpenLDAP client?

Tags: django, logging, openldap

I'm trying to do some authentication inside a Django application using `django-auth-ldap` via the OpenLDAP client.  It's not working so how do I enable some logging?

I CAN make LDAP queries using `ldapsearch` so fundamentally my config is correct and I tried enabling logging for `django-auth-ldap` but it just reports an `Error(0)` which is completely unhelpful.

So how do I enable logging for the OpenLDAP client part of the equation?  Ideally I would like to see what queries it is making and using which config is being passed down from `django-auth-ldap`.  I did find `ldap.conf` but the syntax man page implies there is no logging or debug option.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the answer...

1. To enable logging via the Django LDAP library, add the following to the `settings.py` file for your project

```
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 255
}
```

2. The error that this flushed out was that I was using docker-compose and setting some environment values such as `LDAP_SERVER="ldap://an.ldap.server.com"` - but I should not have been quoting the string as the double-quotes were made part of the value.  Removing these got me moving again.